# Delphi and CreateProcessAsUser example?

Tags: delphi, createprocessasuser

Does anyone have an example of how to use CreateProcessAsUser in Delphi? I'm using Delphi 2009, not the .NET Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at CreateProcAsUser in [JclMiscel](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid5FD38445E2CB2A94256DF70ADAD6811E5DECB19C.aspx) unit from [JCL](http://jcl.delphi-jedi.org/) library

You can use it as easier solution, or you on inspect the code to get how the original one works.

Answer (score 0):

Being a Win32 API function, [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429(VS.85).aspx) works the same way in all languages.

Have you tried [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=CreateProcessAsUser++lang:pascal&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code)? One of the matches is [this one](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#fIgdYqZ7pxM/lgunnars/daplay/ixplorer_src_017.zip%7CDz8irCAR3nM/UConsoleComponent.pas&q=CreateProcessAsUser%20lang:pascal).